# AndroidStudio: Duplicate class found in modules annotations-13.0 and kotlin-compiler-embeddable

Tags: android, kotlin

Updating AndroidStudio this week I was forced to add AnnotationProcessor:

(Don't even understand what for.)

> *Annotation processors must be explicitly declared now.  The following dependencies on the compile classpath are found to contain annotation processor.  Please add them to the annotationProcessor configuration. kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.11.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.3.11)*

So I added to my app.build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
...
annotationProcessor "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:$kotlin_version"
...
}
```

But now I can't get rid of the following errors:

```
Run tasks :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses
> Duplicate class found in  modules annotations-13.0.jar (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0) and kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.11.jar   (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.3.11)
```

I don't know where `org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0` is declared/imported in my gradles or settings.

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a similar Gradle error stating duplicate class found in annotations when I tried to use kotlin in some Old project. In my case, I have to remove the following dependency which was causing conflict with kotlin's annotation module.

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:17.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I got similar error due to some libraries using different versions of the same intellij annotation library.

I run app:dependencies and found that library com.xx.yy is using intellij.annotations.12 dependency. So I exclude that for that library only with

implemenation ("com.xx.yy:1.2.3") {
exclude group: 'com.intellij', module: 'annotations'
}

Answer (score -3):

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

check all dependencies